# what's the purpose of injecting a dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, what's the purpose of injecting a dependency as an array element and as an argument?

For example:

`.controller('foobar', ['$scope','$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {}`

But

`.controller('foobar', function ($scope){}`

is also valid?

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation).

Answer (score 2):

When you minify, the argument names will change and Angular won't be able to resolve them; hence, the array form tells Angular which ones to inject.